# how can i trigger animation of a component in another component

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation

Hello everyone I have a top-nav-component that is responsible for showing and hiding top navigation and it has a nice slide-in-out animation I want to add page transition to my routes.
my routeroutlet is presented in AppComponent

but first, I want my top-nav-component to close first and then page transition happens I don't know how to first close top-nav-component and then do the page transition I am pretty new to angular

Answer (score 0):

One way could be trigger animations on route change. https://angular.io/guide/route-animations

Then time them with delays with `stagger` or `delay`. https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-metadata-duration-delay-and-easing

Let us imagine that current state is so, that user is on a route and `top-nav-component` is showing.

Animation would be following.

1. 250ms + 250ms (500ms) to open or close animate `top-nav-component`

```js
 animate('250ms', style({ height: '*' })),
      query('.menu-item', [
        stagger(-50, [
          animate('250ms ease', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'none' })),
        ]),
      ])
```

2. For the component on route change we give animation where 750ms is time to play route change animation and 500ms is the delay (to wait for `top-nav` animation).

```js
animate('750ms 500ms ease', style({ [direction]: '100%' }))
```

[image]

You can add longer delay for a more noticeable gap.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-animations-bvhn4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Froute-animations.ts